# Не могу становить библиотеку eastocr, помогите мне!

Tags: python, pip

Я уже пробовал перейти на их сайт, почитал информацию. Но как мне ослабить требования верхнего уровня или удалить версии пакетов. Я специально переустановил Windows что бы этой проблемы не было, но она никуда не ушла. Помогите с проблемой. Я знаю что там пакеты между собой не ладят, но как это исправить. Версию ниже тоже пробовал установить. ЯП: Python

```
C:\Users\Digital Angel>pip install easyocr
Collecting easyocr
  Using cached easyocr-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (63.6 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.4-py3-none-any.whl (63.6 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (63.2 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (63.2 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (63.0 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.3-py3-none-any.whl (63.0 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (62.3 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (62.3 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (62.3 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (62.3 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (62.3 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (57.2 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.2-py3-none-any.whl (57.2 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.10-py3-none-any.whl (48.9 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.9-py3-none-any.whl (48.4 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (48.4 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (48.4 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.6-py3-none-any.whl (48.4 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (43.1 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (22.5 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (13.5 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 MB)
  Using cached easyocr-1.0.tar.gz (8.5 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
ERROR: Cannot install easyocr==1.0, easyocr==1.1, easyocr==1.1.1, easyocr==1.1.10, easyocr==1.1.2, easyocr==1.1.3, easyocr==1.1.4, easyocr==1.1.5, easyocr==1.1.6, easyocr==1.1.7, easyocr==1.1.8, easyocr==1.1.9, easyocr==1.2, easyocr==1.2.1, easyocr==1.2.2, easyocr==1.2.3, easyocr==1.2.4, easyocr==1.2.5, easyocr==1.2.5.1, easyocr==1.3, easyocr==1.3.0.1, easyocr==1.3.1, easyocr==1.3.2, easyocr==1.4 and easyocr==1.4.1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    easyocr 1.4.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3.0.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.5.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.5 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.10 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.9 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.8 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.7 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.6 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.5 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.4 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.3 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.2 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.1 depends on torch
    easyocr 1.0 depends on torch

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

Comment: откройте для себя venv, это может стать более легкой альтернативой, чем переустановка windows!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй во 1, скопируй, возможно ты ввёл не ангийский символ

```
pip install easyocr
```

Во 2 попробуй скачать по ссылке копируй

```
pip install git+git://github.com/jaidedai/easyocr.git
```

Comment: К сожалению это не решает мою проблему L1meek. Я написал правильно установку библиотеки так как если бы символы были не английскими то сразу вывелась бы ошибка.